# Importing another table into a database and adding fields

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sequelpro

I have a csv file which I wish to import into my database. However, the columns in the csv file do not match the columns in the table I want to import it into. I would like to do two things:

1. Import the table but only some of the columns
2. Provide default values for columns which the table I am importing does not have.

I hope I explained this well enough. Not too sure how I can add any 'code' for this question, but I have put in some images.

Here is my existing table:

[image: Columns in existing table]

Here are the columns for the csv file I wish to import

[image]

I would like to somehow only import the name (as title), slug, and created_at, updated_at for this csv file into my table. Additionally, I would like the ID to be added automatically, and the 'exam_id' and 'popular' booleans to be set to 0 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is what you need.

Read carefully this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html.

The most interesting part for you is:

> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the LOAD
>   DATA INFILE statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for
>   each table column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns,
>   specify a column list:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata
(col1,col2,...);
```

> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the
>   input file differs from the order of the columns in the table.
>   Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table
>   columns.
>
> The column list can contain either column names or user variables.
>   With user variables, the SET clause enables you to perform
>   transformations on their values before assigning the result to
>   columns.
>
> User variables in the SET clause can be used in several ways. The
>   following example uses the first input column directly for the value
>   of t1.column1, and assigns the second input column to a user variable
>   that is subjected to a division operation before being used for the
>   value of t1.column2:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @var1)   SET
column2 = @var1/100;
```

> The SET clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input
>   file. The following statement sets column3 to the current date and
>   time:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, column2)   SET
column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable
>   and not assigning the variable to a table column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'   INTO TABLE t1   (column1, @dummy,
column2, @dummy, column3);
```